# Can we set event in siri from third party app?

Tags: ios, swift3, siri, sirikit

In one of my Healthcare app I want SIRI to notify patient to weigh themselves every morning in case he forgot.

Is this possible to add event in siri from third party app?
I am positive on that as siri is now iOS 10 allows siri to use in third party app but not sure for this scenario.

Is there any source or thoughts on same?

Comment: You wouldn't add an event to Siri, but rather add a reminder to the users calendar

Answer (score 0):

Siri doesn't do reminders but responds to your queries. What you'd really want is to either add events to the user's calendar (as suggested by Paulw11) or to use remote/local notifications, depending on your requirements.